# mysql: How to select from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables with same key id, but one of them has more records than the other, so an inner join does not work.
the result of my query shows only the common records of the two tables :

```
   t1:
   ---------------------
   id, data
   ----------------------
   1,aaa
   2,bbb
   4,ccc


   t2: 
   -------------------
   id
   -------------------
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5

   join result :
   -------------------
   1,aaa
   2,bbb
   3,null
   4,ccc
   5,null
```

this query does not do the job :

```
$query=" SELECT t2.id, t1.data FROM table1 t1
         INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
         ORDER BY t2.id     " ;
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN` (but t2 should be the first table).

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Please take care when tagging your questions

Comment: "this query does not do the job" is a bad explanation. Do you get an error? Too many rows? Too few?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> create table t1(id int,data varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(4,'ccc');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table t2(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> insert into t2 values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select t2.id,t1.data from t2 left join t1 on (t2.id = t1.id);
+------+------+
| id   | data |
+------+------+
|    1 | aaa  |
|    2 | bbb  |
|    4 | ccc  |
|    3 | NULL |
|    5 | NULL |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this.

```
$query=" SELECT t2.id, t1.data FROM table1 t1
         RIGHT JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
         ORDER BY t2.id" ;
```

Comment: While this works, I would always avoid right outer joins and rewrite the query to use a left outer join instead. Right outer joins are less readable than left outer joins. And rather than "please try this", I'd expect some explanation, e.g. "You need an outer join, so as to keep t2 rows that have no match in t1".

Answer (score 1):

Well, the query that you have provided works as expected for `INNER JOIN` operation.

```
    SELECT t2.id, t1.data 
      FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
  ORDER BY t2.id
```

Will produce:

```
| id | data |
| 1  | aaa  |
| 2  | bbb  |
| 4  | ccc  |
```

If you do want to see all the values from the second table you need to make `LEFT JOIN` operation on the `table2` table.

```
    SELECT t2.id, t1.data 
      FROM table2 t2
 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
        ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Will produce:

```
| id | data   |
| 1  | aaa    |
| 2  | bbb    |
| 3  | (null) |
| 4  | ccc    |
| 5  | (null) |
```

Comment: Only that there are two rows missing in this result compared to the expected one ;-)

Comment: But this is how `INNER JOIN` works. LOL. I have updated the answer, though.